# EmberJs Function from Handlebars

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm learning Ember js by myself and I have this sample code, which works fine:

```
<script>
    window.EmberApp = Ember.Application.create();
    var Marcapagina = Ember.Object.extend({
         convertir_en_link: function() {
            return "<a href='" + this.get("url") + "'>"
            + this.get("nombre")
            + "</a>";
    },
     nombre: "Robert App",
     url: "http://www.google.cl"
    });
</script>
```

And in the html body I get the link printed, this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#here").append(marcapagina.convertir_en_link());
});
</script>
<div id="here"></div>
```

My question is, is there a way to call the function from handlebars, like:

```
<body>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
Here is where i want to print the result of the function, but
{{marcapagina.convertir_en_link()}}
Doesn't works!!!
</script>
```

I want to get rid of this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#here").append(marcapagina.convertir_en_link());
});
</script>
<div id="here"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is using Ember.Objects in a way that is not intended.  But the end result that you're looking for is a very basic and included part of Ember.

[Here's a working jsbin that shows the "Ember Way"](http://jsbin.com/wal/3/edit?html,js,output)

If you're just starting out with ember, I would highly recommend walking through the Todo MVC tutorial [right here](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: Yes, i'm just starting; very nice example, i made a little change to get it to work...cheers ;)